# Broken ground wire in receptacle box

Tags: wiring, receptacle, grounding

I’m pretty new to home DIY and had to replace a few outlets this weekend. On the last one the ground wire snapped as soon as I unscrewed the old outlet. It looks like the wire was clamped to the other ground wires and that’s where it broke. What is the best way to fix my ground connection?

Edit: clearer picture added

[image]

[image]

Comment: There may be a Code issue here if the remaining wire length is less than 6 inches.   This sort of thing is why I like metal boxes... you affix the ground wires to the screw in the back of the box, push the grounds back there behind everything else, *and never touch them again*... switches and self-grounding receps then pick up their grounds via the mounting screws.

Comment: It is not to code in most places to rely on the mounting screws for the ground on any device. You MUST connect a ground wire to the green screw terminal if a device is equipped with one.

Comment: That's a bit surprising. It's no wonder more jurisdictions are adopting IEC instead of NEC. It's also important to know that this is ultimately up to the inspector. Even with NEC, the jurisdiction has the power to utilize only parts of the code.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser NEC itself explicitly permits self-grounding receptacles, as well as switches grounding through the yoke mounting screws.  (I presume by "most places" you mean areas that use 5-continent/European-type power distribution standards?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the crimp connector and use a wire nut to attach a new 6" piece of wire then connect to the screw terminal on your device.

Comment: 99% of time would agree with you, but do not like the look of ground.  Might just be shadow, but black copper should be investigated more.  Would expect end to be bright copper, not black, unless it is an insulated wire with copper in shadow.

Comment: @crip659 -- I think what you're seeing there is a combo of shadow and the paint/drywall mud/texture material on the wire

Comment: It is just a shadow and some paint, the ground wire is a bright copper color. The neutrals on a couple outlets in this room were burned and the insulation was charred though. One of the outlets was completely shot due to painters getting paint deep in the outlet (my theory at least). That was the charred one, the other was just a light brown. I cut back the wire to good insulation and stripped them before installing the new outlets. Is there a bigger problem than 50 year old outlets going on here?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel possible, but copper usually does not snap off and the snapped off end is black also.  I would like to be there to make sure.

Comment: Would hope those painters out of business.  Age of outlets should not matter unless they have loose/worn/bad connections(paint inside).  @Bean should edit your comment to your question, since it adds new information, burnt neutrals and paint inside outlets.

Comment: Without seeing the original wires as removed from the wall, it's hard to pass judgment on the cause of the overheated wires. I find it highly doubtful that it was the paint. Many times this will happen when wires are poorly terminated in daisy chained outlets and the homeowner uses a space heater in the last outlet.

Comment: @crip659 Not sure what to do and don’t want to make the question about more than one thing. The burnt neutrals weren’t on this receptacle but one with light browning was on the same circuit. I think it was paint in both cases for the burnt neutrals and fried outlet but again, still new to all this.

Comment: Are the devices terminated with the screw terminals or the push-ins?

Comment: @ScienceGeyser the old ones were push-ins, new ones are all screws. And these outlets are daisy chained ending in a garage outlet that probably saw heavy use.

Comment: Push-ins are notorious for overheating under heavy loads. This is especially true for the 49 cent devices that are often used.

Comment: @crip659 I don't think any part of the copper is black, it looks like a phone camera with no HDR getting overwhelmed by the contrast of an up-close flash on shiny materials; further, OP has stated the bare copper is not black. Note the short wire (I presume the one you're calling black) is only half dark, and half white. It's exactly what I'd expect of a diked wire where the cut is a "V" shape -- half the face is reflecting the flash and is white, the other half is shadowed by that and appears black.

Comment: @Doktor J second picture makes the copper look good compared to first, which was all we had at the time.

Comment: @crip659 ah, didn't realize the second picture was edited in. Maybe I just spend too much time taking pictures with crappy equipment and am all too familiar with strange lighting situations 